# Firebase Realtime Database read rule for specific user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How can I add new rule to Firebase Realtime Database so that users can read data where `recid` equal to user ID?

I have a massage table with this structure:

```
"messages" : {
    "-KyyjeMOtc7fWAsOiuiP" : {
      "recid" : "FL5hyQJrsHWRQsRtiLe1PxkyRnk1",
      "senderid" : "6K6pQHaCishDlCb0Y9AaN3zI22n1",
      "text" : "hi"
    },
    "-KyykczCNpsSL6a1t8vt" : {
      "recid" : "FL5hyQJrsHWRQsRtiLe1PxkyRnk1",
      "senderid" : "6K6pQHaCishDlCb0Y9AaN3zI22n1",
      "text" : "test"
    },
  }
```

I want a rule that when data is added to the database, only the user whose `uid` is equal to `recid` can see the data.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer can be improved. Or, if it helped you, feel free to [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you can create [user-based security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) for your database, something similar to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$messageId": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == data.child('recid').val()",
        ".write": "auth !== null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, `$messageId` uses a [`$location` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#location) that will match any key under your `messages` list. Then, we grant read access only if the [current user's `auth.uid`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#auth) matches the `recid` child value.

Comment: I know the question was only asking about read access, but I think it should be pointed out that with these rules users are still able to modify/delete other users' messages

Comment: tanks  @dbandstra how to prevent modify/delete other users' messages?

Comment: Off the top of my head, it should be `".write": "!data.exists() || auth.uid == data.child('senderid').val()"`. Now, anyone can create, but only sender can modify/delete. I think the rules still need more work after this though. You should probably give sender read access too. And only allow him to modify the `text` field, not the `recid`/`senderid` fields. Are you new to firebase? Do you have a working app using this db?

Comment: Can someone show the path of the database reference used in app? If in path ```messageId``` is used then this solution won't work. I am trying to do the same in my app and it do not work